# Mark as PSR compliant at file level

Tags: phpstorm, psr-4, autoformatting, psr-0

I'm working in a codebase that is *not* fully PSR compliant at this point. Auto format can not be enabled as that would lead to a massive amount changes in pull requests.

We're now working through the file, normalizing as we go and making everything compliant. These files are "clean" and are fully compliant.

I'm looking for a way to mark these files as done and compliant and enable auto-format by PhpStorm or a plugin which does that. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There are no such stuff. If you want, you may put whole file content between `@formatter:off` and `@formatter:on` tags that tells IDE to not to apply any code formatting here. See help page for details/examples: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-code-style.html#93abe77b

Comment: If you are formatting a bunch of files at once -- consider using custom scope instead, this way you may include only desired files (but why would you need to reformat the same file multiple times?) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-code-on-directory-dialog.html

Comment: Hm, that appears to be the exact inverse if what I want. That assumes the default is on, and you can turn it off. I want it off and turn it on. But it's at least acceptable for the human factor to notice, it's something :)